# Can I show results of previous to prospective clients - i.e. keyword position data?

Tags: seo, clients, seo-competition-analysis

I've been building an SEO business over the last couple of years on my own. I have a couple clients who've seen great results over the last 6 - 12 months.

I would like to be able to share with a prospective client some of the results from these two clients. If I were to share keyword ranking data, even without revealing the client's name, could potentially be sharing valuable data if a competitor were to come across it? In some ways, anyone with and SEO Tool, could enter the url for this client, and find the keywords they are tracking for.

The alternative to this is simply to provide stats, number of keywords, how many have jumped, average increase overall etc.

Does anyone have advice on the best to go about showing a future client results I've achieved. What do you do yourselves?

Hope this isn't a stupid question. I am on the verge of having enough successful examples to build case study/client testimonial page, but at this stage, I just want to win this next client, as it's a great opportunity for me.

Leah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share my way of winning SEO projects:

Yes, of course you can share your previous results to the new clients to convince them. But never reveal your complete strategy.

Like you can share previous rankings of keywords, but never give a complete list of keywords, give few keywords which are really performing well, give screenshots of google analytics for showing traffic reports and goal conversation if any.

I think above things are enough to prove your SEO skills, moreover, you can prepare a basic SEO Audit report for them.

**NOTE:** If you are going to convince the client in same niche you worked previously then be aware. Because your previous and new clients can be competitors. Keep this thing in mind while sharing reports and keywords.